# How to use curl with a variable in c

Tags: c, curl

I have a program that stores an RSS feed in a linked list. My dilemma is that the url for a specific feed is stored in a structure element. How do I curl a variable?

```
    void get_feed(int holder, struct node *head){

    struct node *temp = head;
    char *feed_url = 0;

    while(temp->position != holder){
            temp = temp->link;
    }

    feed_url = temp->url;

    system("curl feed_url -o feed.txt") //doesn't work
```

Comment: Why don't you program against the `libcurl` instead of calling `system()`?

Answer (score 2):

You need `sprintf()`/`snprintf()`, if you are expecting you program to recieve input from `curl`'s output, then `system()` will not let you do that.

Example:

```
char command[100];
int  result;

result = snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "curl -o %s %s", url, filename);
if (result >= sizeof(command))
    oopsTheBufferIsTooSmall();
system(command);
```